# Ruby IO redirection to a file by using Kernel.puts,How can I ensure that the stored file's encoding type is ANSI or UTF-8

Tags: ruby, redirect, encoding, io, error-code

In windows: visual studio code IDE,I wrote the command like:

> ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts '汤姆,Welcome to my home'" > test.txt

,then I use the command:

> ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts gets" < test.txt

,but error codes occurred when reading.Like:

> ��ķ,Welcome to my home.

[image]

Finally I found the "test.txt" file's encoding type is unicode.

If I insist on using IO redirection to a file and choose kernel.puts, how can I ensure that the stored file's encoding type is UTF-8?

What should I do to ensure that the file encoding type after redirection is UTF-8?Please help me.

Comment: Maybe it's the dreaded BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Comment: @steenslag, no it's about the _active code page_, which must first be set to UTF-8 with `chcp 65001` (works in `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) only, not in PowerShell).

Comment: em...you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot implies that **you're using `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt), the legacy Windows shell**.<sup>[1]</sup>

By default, it uses the system's active legacy OEM code page, which is typically a fixed 8-bit character encoding limited to 256 characters, i.e. a *single-byte* encoding, e.g. [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems, as reported when you run `chcp`.

**If you want `cmd.exe` to use UTF-8 encoding instead, run `chcp 65001` first**.

---

For character-encoding considerations with respect to *PowerShell*, `cmd.exe`'s modern successor, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996295/45375) to your related [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74992859/45375).

---

<sup>[1] This is implied by two facts: the prompt string in your screenshots looks something like `C:\path>` and has *no space* after it (unlike in PowerShell, where it is also preceded by `PS` ) and you're successfully using `<` for input redirection, which, between `cmd.exe` and PowerShell, only `cmd.exe` supports (in PowerShell it causes an error).</sup>

Comment: Yes,you are right.It's cmd.exe