# What 's the reason of Ruby IO stream in Windows powershell file type encoding

Tags: ruby, powershell, encoding, stream, file-type

I have a strangeness problem. In Windows7 operation system,I try to run the command in powershell.

> ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts 'どうぞよろしくお願いします,Mr Jason'" > test.txt

When I read test.txt file:

> ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts gets" < test.txt

the result is:

> �i0F0^0�0�0W0O0J0X�D0W0~0Y0,Mr Jason

I check test.txt file,find the file type encoding is Unicode,not UTF-8.

What should I do ?

How should I ensure the encoding of the output file type after redirection? Please help me.

Comment: can you take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163339/write-and-read-a-file-with-utf-8-encoding and see if you can get that to help?

Comment: Em...I saw the anwser,In fact,It should be powershell command combine with ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Unfortunately, the solution (on Windows) is much more complicated than one would hope:

```bash
# Make PowerShell both send and receive data as UTF-8 when talking to
# external (native) programs.
# Note: 
#  * In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, $OutputEncoding *defaults* to UTF-8.
#  * You may want to save and restore the original settings.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
 
# Create a BOM-less UTF-8 file.
# Note: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can less obscurely use:
#   ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts 'どうぞよろしくお願いします,Mr Jason'" | Set-Content test.txt
$null = New-Item -Force test.txt -Value (
  ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts 'どうぞよろしくお願いします,Mr Jason'"
)

# Pipe the resulting file back to Ruby as UTF-8, thanks to $OutputEncoding
# Note that PowerShell has NO "<" operator - stdin input must be provided
# via the pipeline.
Get-Content -Raw test.txt | ruby -E UTF-8 -e "puts gets"
```

---

- In terms of *character encoding*, PowerShell communicates with external (native) programs via two settings that contain .NET [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding) instances:

  - `$OutputEncoding` specifies the encoding to use to send data TO an external program via the pipeline.
  - `[Console]::OutputEncoding` specifies the encoding to interpret (decoded) data FROM an external program('s stdout stream); for decoding to work as intended, this setting must match the external program's actual output encoding.
- As of PowerShell 7.3.1, PowerShell only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs, and an *intermediate decoding and re-encoding step is invariably involved* - even when you're just using `>` (effectively an alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlets) to send output to a file.

  - That is, PowerShell's pipelines are NOT *raw byte conduits* the way the are in other shells.

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for workarounds and potential future raw-byte support.
  - Whatever output operator (`>`) or cmdlet (`Out-File`, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)) you use will use *its* default character encoding, which is unrelated to the encoding of the original input, which *has already been decoded into .NET strings* when the operator / cmdlet operates on it.

    - `>` / `Out-File` in *Windows PowerShell* defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoding, which is what you saw.
    - While `Out-File` and `Set-Content` have an `-Encoding` parameter that allows you to control the output encoding, in *Windows PowerShell* they don't allow you to create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files; curiously, [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) *does* create such files, which is why it is used above; if a UTF-8 BOM is acceptable, `... | Set-Content -Encoding utf8` will do in Windows PowerShell.
    - Note that, by  contrast, [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern, cross-platform edition now thankfully consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.

      - That said, with respect to `[Console]::OutputEncoding` on Windows, it still uses the legacy OEM code page by default as of v7.3.1, which means that UTF-8 output from external programs is by default *misinterpreted* - see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) for a discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much.By the way,I run the command in powershell v2 .echo  "すみません" | ruby -e "puts gets"，But output gibberish like "??????"，what should I do?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Jason; given that you've since also accepted this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996706/45375), which explains the `??????` problem, I assume your follow-up question has been answered as well.