# powershell V2 echo "すみません" | ruby -e "puts gets" occur gibberish

Tags: ruby, powershell, encode

In powershell(v2) condition,I run the command,it goes gibberish.

echo "すみません" | ruby -e "puts gets"

> ?????

[image]

My powershell is V2.How should I get the correct output?

Comment: What error code?

Comment: What are your Ruby and Windows versions?

Comment: As an aside: `?????` is the `ruby` call's _output string_, not an _error_. It is the lossy to-ASCII encoding performed by PowerShell on sending the data to Ruby that converts the unsupported-in-ASCII characters to literal `?` chars. (question marks).

Comment: output gibberish like "??????",I try to run: echo “すみません” |Ruby -e “put gets.force_encoding('UTF-8')”，but still output gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996295/45375) to your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74992859/45375), you need to set `$OutputEncoding` / `[Console]::OutputEncoding` first to match the character encoding that `ruby` expects / outputs; e.g., for **UTF-8**:

```bash
# Make PowerShell both send and receive data as UTF-8 when talking to
# external (native) programs.
# Note: 
#  * In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, $OutputEncoding *defaults* to UTF-8.
#  * You may want to save and restore the original settings.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

echo "すみません" | ruby -e "puts gets"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

With Windows PowerShell using ASCII(!) encoding by default when sending data via the pipeline to external programs (see below), characters such as `す` can NOT be represented, and get "lossily" translated to *literal `?`* characters.

Since *none* of the characters in your input string have an ASCII representation, the (ASCII representation of) verbatim string `?????`
was sent to `ruby`.

---

##### Background information:

In PowerShell it is the [**`$OutputEncoding`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) that determines the encoding used for sending data TO external programs, and in ***Windows PowerShell*** it defaults to **ASCII**(!), i.e. only characters in the 7-bit ASCII subrange of Unicode can be represented.

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, `$OutputEncoding` now more sensibly defaults to (BOM-less) **UTF-8**.

Unfortunately, with respect to *receiving* data from external programs, where  **[`[Console]::OutputEncoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.OutputEncoding)** matters for correct interpretation of the output, even PowerShell (Core) 7+ **still uses the legacy OEM code page by default** as of v7.3.1, which means that UTF-8 output from external programs is by default *misinterpreted* - see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) for a discussion.